# Python - iterate through list in threaded script

Tags: python, multithreading

I am trying to write a threaded Python script which will iterate through a list of urls and open each one in a separate thread.

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
from threading import Thread
import mechanize

tickers = ["aapl", "siri", "goog", "intc"]
nextTicker = 0

def quotes(i):
    br = mechanize.Browser()
    br.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT   6.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.10) Gecko/20100914 Firefox/3.6.10')]
    r= br.open('http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=' + tickers[nextTicker])
    html = r.read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
    price = soup.findAll('span', attrs={"id":"yfs_l10_" + tickers[nextTicker]})
    price = price[0].string
    print price

for i in range(4):
    t = Thread(target=quotes, args=(i,))
    t.start()
```

I know that I need a `nextTicker = nextTicker + 1` in there so that each thread will grab a unique ticker symbol from the list named tickers but I am not sure where to put this or how to ensure that each thread is getting a unique url.

Right now when the script runs it just grabs the index 0 item from the list for all four threads. How do I get each thread to grab the next item in the list and append it to my base url?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want thread specific data, pass it in the arguments.

So use tickers[i] instead of tickers[nextTicker]

Better yet, use

```
for ticker in tickers:
   t = Thread(target = quotes, args = (ticker,) )
```

Possibly better yet, checkout eventlet. It allows writing code like this but avoids some of the problems with threads.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up concerning eventlet. I checked it out and I and made a new script with it.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of meddling with a `nextTicker` variable and having to lock it and so forth, just refer to `tickers[i]`. (Or even better, just pass the ticker itself!)